# Why doesn't this command equivalent work in R?

Tags: r

I am currently attending an R training where the trainer says:

```
b <- array(1:12, c(2,3,2))
```

is equivalent to

```
D <- 1:12
dim(D) <- c(2,3,2)
```

If this is the case then why does

```
b <- array(1:12, c(2,3,3))
```

work, but

```
D <- 1:12
dim(D) <- c(2,3,3)
```

does not?

I did ask my trainer, but the answer I got is not convincing to me.

Comment: @jay.sf yes. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Please look up the documentation and input parameters of function array.
    array(data = , dim = , dimnames = ).
Here 
    b <- array(1:12, c(2,3,3)) 
you are giving c(2,3,3) as the dimensions, which you then are changing to 
    `D <- 1:12`
    `dim(D) <- c(2,3,2)`
Thus b != D.